# Providing Help Contents with Java Program

Tags: java, google-code

What is the best practice for providing "Help Contents" in a Java Application. Should I use ".CHM" files, do Linux operating systems have built-in support for ".CHM" files? I was thinking of how I was going to host my project and I was looking into Google Code Projects and that seems perfect for my needs, so should I just redirect them to the support section of my Google Code Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web based help is preferable in my mind, as you can modify/update it after the application is released. If the help is bundled with the application, you would need to re-release the application if you want to change the help.

Comment: I've decided to just use Google Code Project Hosting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would go for a [JEditorPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) displaying HTML or rich text (RTF) content. The application could find help updates by [fetching new content](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Showwebpage.htm) from a URL, or displaying a cached version of the content in case of failure. In any case, your help files are clean and easily maintainable, and compliant with Java's component (OS independent).